# Saved image not retrievable - android

Tags: android, kotlin

Im saving an image using the below code.

```
val cw = ContextWrapper(applicationContext)
val directory =
        cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val file = File(directory, Utility().replaceSpaces(categoryName) + ".png")
if (!file.exists()) {
Log.d("path", file.toString())
var fos: FileOutputStream? = null
try {
     fos = FileOutputStream(file)
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
     fos.flush()
     fos.close()
     } catch (e: IOException) {
         e.printStackTrace()
     }
}
```

Im retrieving the image using the following code.

```
val uri =
    if (category.isEmpty()) "@drawable/appicon"
    else "@drawable/${Utility().replaceSpaces(category)}"
var image = resources.getIdentifier(uri, null, packageName)

if (image == 0)
    image = resources.getIdentifier("@drawable/appicon", null, packageName)

val imageView = ImageView(this)
```

when retrieved the image is always 0

Comment: You're writing the image into the `imageDir` directory, but you're trying to fetch it from the resources, this won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Im saving an image using the below code

You do not need the `ContextWrapper`.

> Im retrieving the image using the following code

That is some rather strange code for attempting to get a resource identifier. Resources cannot be modified at runtime, and your saved image is not a resource.

Instead, create a `File` object the same way that you did in your first code snippet. Then, hand that `File` object to an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso. They can read in and decode the image on a background thread, then update your `ImageView` with the result.